# Firestore's getDocs() function does not get fulfilled or rejected for me when I try to use it to fetch a list of data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am trying to fetch a collection (called books) of documents from my firestore with getDocs() function.

However, it does not seem to return any results (a Promise that does not get fulfilled or rejected) and the rest of the code below it does not get executed.

Here in my React App component, I am trying to fetch a list of books when it mounts. However, the execution of the code within useEffect function stopped at `const allDocs = await firebaseService.getAllDocuments('books');`. Within the getAllDocuments method defined in firebase.js below, the getDocs function just doesn't return anything (or fulfilled/rejected). It just stopped within it and .. nothing happened.

```
// App.jsx

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './app.css';

import FirebaseService from '../../services/Firebase.js';
import { AuthProvider } from './AuthProvider.jsx';
// other imports of route views omitted for brevity..

const firebaseService = new FirebaseService();
const App = () => {

    const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

    useEffect(async () => {
        console.log('1') // runs
        const allDocs = await firebaseService.getAllDocuments('books');
        setBooks(allDocs); // line does not run
        console.log('2') // does not run
    }, []);

    return (
        <div id="container" className='inner-container'>
            <AuthProvider>
                <BrowserRouter basename="/">
                // some routes here..
                </BrowserRouter>
            </AuthProvider>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I've abstracted my Firebase as a service into it's own class. The addDocument method works in another component where I create new individual documents. However, the getAllDocuments method does not work when trying to use it in App.jsx

// Firebase.js

```
import {
    getAuth,
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword,
    signOut
} from 'firebase/auth';

import {
    getFirestore,
    collection,
    collectionGroup,
    addDoc,
    getDocs,
    onSnapshot,
    query,
    where
} from 'firebase/firestore';
const firebaseConfig = {
// all the necessary configs like apiKey, appId, etc..
};


class FirebaseService {
    constructor() {
        this.firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        this.auth = getAuth(this.firebaseApp);
        this.firestore = getFirestore(this.firebaseApp);
    }

    // Auth APIs
    async signUp(email, password) {// some implementation}

    async signIn(email, password) {// some implementation}

    async signOut() {// some implementation}

    // Firestore APIs
    async addDocument(collectionName, data) {
        try {
            const collectionRef = collection(this.firestore, collectionName);
            const documentRef = await addDoc(collectionRef, data);
            console.log('Document added with ID:', documentRef.id);
            return documentRef;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error adding document:', error.message);
            throw error;
        }
    }

    async getAllDocuments(collectionName) {
        try {
            const q = query(collection(this.firestore, collectionName));
            console.log('1'); // runs
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
            console.log('2'); // does not run
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            })
            return querySnapshot;
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error getting documents:', error.message);
            throw error;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my setup in firestore
[Firestore Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBlHU.png)
[Firestore Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R8dx.png)

Please let me know if more info is needed. Really need help with this.

Comment: As a first step in debugging, I recommend putting a `try catch` around the `await` you have and logging any errors you get.

Comment: hello @FrankvanPuffelen I have added the try catch block in the method, getAllDocuments, in Firebase.js, however, did not get any errors since it does not return anything (fulfilled / rejected) for me.